# Can i get EC2 IPV4 back after stop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipv4

I stopped by EC2 instance to do some maintenance and after I started I got a new IP. bummer. I made an elastic IP to make sure it does not change again, but i still have people calling the old IP, is there any way to claim that recently lost IP associated to my Ec2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't get that old public IP back. Try to always use DNS names to avoid this kind of issues in the future.

Look at [this official answer](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=150046) to a similar question.

Comment: Thanks. you are right. I am still fighting for it though. I see when we launch a new instance, we have the option to provide IP we want to associate, that seems one possibility but yet trying.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-private-primary-address-ec2/

Comment: @SatinderSidhu that's for the *private* IP address.  Your public IP is gone.